# Get iterator for const reference

Tags: c++, stl

I'm developing a class that must return an iterator with the `begin()` method. Also, I have to develop a function that receives a const reference of this class and iterates over it.

When I try to get an iterator from this method, I have the following compilation error: `"the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function."`I can't understand why this error appears.

Here is the code that I have written:

```
// ------------ class Neuron -------------
class Neuron { ... };
// ---------------------------------


// ------------ class AbstractLayer -------------
class AbstractLayer {
public:

    class Iterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, Neuron> {
        public:
            Iterator(Neuron *neurons) : _neurons(neurons) {}
        private:
            Neuron *_neurons;
    };

    virtual Iterator begin() = 0;
    virtual const Iterator begin2() = 0;
};
// ----------------------------------------


// ------------ class Layer -------------
class Layer : AbstractLayer {

public:
    Layer(){};
    Iterator begin(){ return Iterator(_neurons); }
    const Iterator begin2(){ return (const Iterator)begin(); }

private:
    Neuron *_neurons;
    int _size;
};
// --------------------------------


// ------------ Method where the problem is -------------------
void method(const AbstractLayer &layer){
    // Error in both methods: 
    // "the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function."
    layer.begin();
    layer.begin2();
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `method` function, `layer` references a *constant* object. That means you can only call functions marked as `const`. Like e.g.

```
class AbstractLayer {
public:
    ...
    virtual const Iterator begin() const = 0;  // <- Note use of `const` here
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function accepts a `const AbstractLayer` which means that only `const` member functions can be called on it. However, `begin` and `begin2` are not `const`. In fact, given that only `begin2` returns a `const Iterator`, it wouldn't make sense to try and call `begin` anyway in this method.

Change

```
virtual const Iterator begin2() = 0;
```

to

```
virtual const Iterator begin2() const = 0;
```

and

```
const Iterator begin2()
```

to

```
const Iterator begin2() const
```

Finally, returning a `const Iterator` is actually meaningless in your code, as the `const` is discarded on account of an rvalue being returned. Regardless, you shouldn't need to perform casting to `const Iterator` when you call `begin`; just return an `Iterator` and the compiler will take care to make it const.

Finally, your `Layer` class needs to derive publicly from `AbstractLayer`:

```
class Layer : public AbstractLayer
```

### [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f106071505c47cf3)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `begin` and `begin2`. What you need is two versions of `begin` - const and non-const. A const one would return const iterator. You also might want a `cbegin` (const only) which would always return const iterator.

Answer (score 0):

In `method`, the `layer` argument is const which prevents you from calling non-const methods on it.  If you take layer by non-const reference (`void method(AbstractLayer &layer)`), you will be able to call both methods.

You should probably provide a const `begin` method that returns a `const_iterator` so you can iterate over a const `AbstractLayer`.