# Does `const_iterator` really need to be a different class than `iterator`?

Tags: c++, constructor, iterator, constants, const-iterator

Let say I define some kind of container `A`:

```
struct A
{
    iterator begin(){ return iterator(this,0); }
    const iterator cbegin() const { return iterator(this, last());}
    //...
};
```

Suppose now I want to declare the `iterator` (part of A):

```
struct A::iterator
{
    iterator ( A* ptr, size_t idx){};
    //...
};
```

Which I would use like:

```
const A a;
A::iterator it = a.cbegin();
```

That does not work because the pointer passed to the constructor of `iterator` is non-const.

The ideal solution would be something like a specific constructor that return a const object:

```
const A::iterator( const StringUtfInterface *p, size_t s); //Not valid
```

This is (obviously) not valid in C++. I wonder what is the approach to this problem?

Do I really need to declare/define a new const_iterator class? `const` keyword is not enough?

---

Related questions (but not the same):

- [Why does C++ not have a const constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936124/why-does-c-not-have-a-const-constructor)
- [Get iterator for const reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919822/get-iterator-for-const-reference)

Comment: The difference between an iterator, a const iterator and a const_iterator is the same as between a regular pointer (`T *`), a const pointer (`T * const`) and a pointer to const (`T const *`). You need all three kinds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `const` keyword is not enough?

Actually, `const` keyword is too much: it forces you to write

```
const A::iterator it = a.cbegin();
```

which prevents you from using `++it` later on.

You need to provide two separate classes, but it does not mean that you have to write the code twice. You can structure an implementation of your iterator in such a way that a common class that does all the work is embedded in both constant and non-constant iterator implementations, which expose the relevant methods of the embedded implementation to the callers.

Comment: Do you recommend to extend const_iterator from iterator, iterator from const_iterator, or using template for const/non-const type?

Comment: @AdrianMaire I would not extend non-const `iterator` from `const_iterator`, because they provide the same member functions and operators returning objects of different type. Using a template would probably work, but I think it would be somewhat harder that wrapping a common implementation into two separate classes, or even privately inheriting from a common base if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

What about just overloading the constructor of `iterator` to support constant container too?

```
struct A::iterator {
    iterator(A* ptr, size_t idx) {}
    iterator(const A* ptr, size_t idx) {}
    //...
};
```

In this way it is not necessary to define two separate classes and you will always obtain (implicitly) the right iterator depending on your container constness.

**UPDATE**

Following comment, you may use a template such as (not full implementation)

```
struct A {
  template<class T>
  struct base_iterator {
  private:
    T* _ptr;

  public:
    base_iterator(T* ptr, size_t idx) : _ptr(ptr) {}

    T operator*() { return *_ptr; }
    //...
  };

  typedef base_iterator<A> iterator;
  typedef base_iterator<const A> const_iterator;

  iterator begin() { return iterator(this, 0); }
  const_iterator cbegin() const { return const_iterator(this, 0); }
  //...
};
```

Comment: What type are you going to return from `operator*`?

Comment: Oh! I see the point... it is obvious now that I haven't implemented too many iterators, isn't it? ;)

Comment: Using a template `base_iterator` may work, but keep in mind you need to make `base_iterator<const T>` constructable from `base_iterator<T>`.