# C++ Writing const vectors with pointers to non const

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, constants

I am writing a CustomVector class, internally storing data using a standard vector:

```
template <class T>
class CustomVector {
  friend class CustomVector_ref<T>;

  public:
  ...

  private:
    std::vector<T> _data;
};
```

Then, in order to extract subvectors from CustomVector, I use a class storing pointers to each element of data:

```
template <class T>
class CustomVector_ref {
  public:
    //Returns the value stored in CustomVector 
    //and pointed-to by _data_ref
    T& operator[] (size_t id) { return *_data_ref[id] } 
    const T& operator[] const (size_t id) { return *_data_ref[id] } 
  ...
  private:
    std::vector<T*> _data_ref;
};
```

Now, to illustrate my problem it is sufficient to consider the simple costructor building a reference to all the elements of CustomVector

```
template<class T>
CustomVector_ref<T>::CustomVector_ref(CustomVector<T>& cv)
{
  for (T& el : cv._data)
    _data_ref.push_back(&el);
}
```

That works fine, but if I have a const CustomVector, I need also to define the constructor:

```
template<class T>
CustomVector_ref<T>::CustomVector_ref(const CustomVector<T>& cv)
{
  for (const T& el : cv._data)
  _data_ref.push_back(const_cast<T*>(&el));
}
```

That works too, but if the CustomVector_ref object is not declared as const, then with the non-const operator [] it is possible to write data into the const CustomVector object.

```
const CustomVector<int> cv(...) //CostumVector is somehow constructed, 
                                //that does not matter now

std::cout<<cv[0]<<std::endl;  //output 1 for example

CustomVector_ref<int> cvr(cv)

cvr[0] = 2;

std::cout<<cv[0]<<std::endl;  //now cv[0] stores 2
```

It is possible to avoid this behavior?

I have noticed that this happens also with standard vectors, for example

```
const std::vector<int> v(1,1);
std::vector<int*> vp;

vp.push_back(const_cast<int*>(&v[0]));

*vp[0] = 2;

std::cout<<v[0]<<std::endl;  // now v[0] stores 2, not 1
```

So, since this is standard C++, I do not bother too much to fix my CustomVector, but it would be nice to know if there is a (not too convoluted) solution.

Comment: You need to ponder on the simple fact that standard library containers define two different iterator classes: `iterator` and `const_iterator`. There's a good reason for that, and you've just discovered what that reason is. Your situation is completely analogous. You need to implement two different references, a mutable and a `const` reference. For extra credit, the mutable reference should be castable to the `const` reference, so it can be passed to functions that take `const` references as arguments.

Comment: hesitating to flag it as dupe, but this is closely realted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882363/does-const-iterator-really-need-to-be-a-different-class-than-iterator

Comment: What about using `CustomVector_ref<const int>`? No const_cast needed this way

Comment: @geza That would work, and in that case, without const_cast, it would not be possible to write into const CustomVector objects, as anyone would expect. But I think it is more natural to declare a CustomVector_ref<T> as a reference of a CustomVector<T>, even if it is const. But I will consider your suggestion.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Why not make that an answer?

Comment: @geza If I'm not mistaken, const on template parameters are ignored (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435235/const-in-template-argument )

Comment: @VTolmer: for `const int`, sure, it's ignored. But for typename parameters (which is the case here), they are not ignored.

Comment: Btw const_cast is a dangerous thing - using variable with cast out const leads to UB

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to prevent modification of the original vector regardless of whether `CustomVector_ref` was initialized with a `const` or `non-const` version of the vector?  If so, you can do this by simply changing the return type of `operator[]`, as follows:

```
template <class T>
class CustomVector_ref {
  public:
    ...
    const T& operator[] (size_t id) { return *_data_ref[id] } 
    const T& operator[] const (size_t id) { return *_data_ref[id] } 
  ...
};
```

Note that storing pointers into the original vector is dangerous.  If the original vector's size changes, all your pointer values may be invalidated.

If you want to change the behavior of `CustomVector_ref` depending on whether it's constructed with a `const` or `non-const` version of the original vector, you'll need to change the signature of the template in order to be able to differentiate between `const` and `non-const` versions of the original vector.  An example implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class CustomVector_ref {
public:
  CustomVector_ref(T& orig_vector) : m_vector_ref(orig_vector) {}

  auto& operator[] (size_t id) { return m_vector_ref[id]; }
  const typename T::value_type& operator[] (size_t id)  const { return m_vector_ref[id]; }

  private:
  T& m_vector_ref;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::vector<int> my_vec({1, 2, 3});
  std::cout << my_vec[0] << std::endl;

  CustomVector_ref<std::vector<int>> cv_ref(my_vec);
  cv_ref[0] = 2; // Assignment is ok; non-const cv_ref initialized with a non-const vector
  std::cout << cv_ref[0] << std::endl;  //now cv[0] stores 2

  CustomVector_ref<const std::vector<int>> cv_cref(my_vec);
  // cv_cref[0] = 2; // Compile error: assignment of read-only location
  const_cast<int&>(cv_cref[0]) = 2; // Explicit override of const
  std::cout << cv_cref[0] << std::endl;

  const std::vector<int> my_const_vec({1, 2, 3});
  // CustomVector_ref<std::vector<int>> cv_cref2(my_const_vec); // Compile error; non-const initialization from const
  CustomVector_ref<const std::vector<int>> cv_cref3(my_const_vec); // Ok, const initialization from const
  // cv_cref3[0] = 2; // Compile error: assignment of read-only location
  const_cast<int&>(cv_cref3[0]) = 2; // Explicit override of const
  std::cout << cv_cref3[0] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```